# Are popular questions being gamed and spammed?

Tags: discussion, spam

I did some searching for Java decompilers and came across some strange answers on the big SO questions.

On a [4 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler/17589041#17589041), the top answer from 4 years ago has 21 votes. Yet an answer less than a week old, from a user less than 10 days old and linking to a commercial website, has 20 votes!

Similiar answers from other suspect users that I could find are as follows:

[Java Decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375037/java-decompiler/17589241#17589241)

[Choose and test java decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898391/choose-and-test-java-decompiler/17520501#17520501)

[How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files/17580055#17580055)

They all link to the Secureteam product and have a crazy amount of votes in relation to their posting time.

Comment: ...three users, all last seen on July 11 at the same time of day, two created on the same day. I'm guessing Sutton is the "real" user. Good detective work!

Comment: animuson is on the case...

Answer (score 26):

Nice catch. This is an organized group of spammers who apparently work for the company with the products in question. They somehow slipped through with innocuous-looking questions and answers (copied from other users), then built a massive voting ring to prop each other up. They've been trying to spam these products for the last two years, it looks like.

We destroyed 18 accounts that were part of this ring, and cleaned up the mess they made in their posts.

If you see this again, flag us about it and we'll look into things. Also, I often find it helpful to run a quick `url:spamdomain.com` search to see if this is part of a larger trend. That's one of the ways I found their other accounts.

Comment: Do you search for that URL using the regular search?

Comment: @Seth - Yes, if you go on any SE site and use the search there, a `url:whateverdomain.com` search will find all posts that contain a link leading to that domain.

Comment: awww... all that SEO juice spilt! ;)

Comment: cool, I didn't know whether to just flag the questions or post on meta as I've never seen this type of spamming on SO. It's strange as the product they were spamming is actually pretty good! It's a good JavaFX frontend of a new Java OS decompiler developed by Mike Strobel. Mike even added a comment on the spam post saying it's probably the easiest way to use his code. If they hadn't been so greedy or blatant in their upvoting, nobody would have noticed.

Comment: NO! Those were my sock puppets!

Answer (score 11):

In the general case, that's why we close these questions. They *do* attract spam and we don't want that. As far as it being "gamed" - I guess that depends on your definition. They're opinion-based answers at the least, so posting something there is a bit of a gamble for upvotes and downvotes depending on who views it and agrees or disagrees.

In this specific case:

[image: Move along, nothing to see here.]

Comment: kaboom! Yay! Woohoo!